# How to change a Visualforce Page UI to Lightning

Tags: visualforce

I am using this code for a Visualforce page. I created this VF page to have a files related list without the "Upload Files" button. Is there any way to make this UI better and closer aligned to Lightning UI?

This is my code:

```
<apex:page >
<apex:relatedList subject="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}"  list="CombinedAttachments">
<apex:facet name="header"><table><tr><td class="pbTitle"><h3>Files</h3></td></tr></table></apex:facet>
</apex:relatedList>
</apex:page>
```

Here is the current UI:[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `apex:slds` tag. Allows Visualforce pages to reference Lightning Design System styling

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="true" applyBodyTag="false">
<head>
    <apex:slds />
</head>
 <body>
    <apex:relatedList subject="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}"  list="CombinedAttachments">
     <apex:facet name="header">
       <table>
        <tr>
         <td class="pbTitle">
           <h3>Files</h3>. 
          </td>
        </tr>
       </table>
     </apex:facet>
   </apex:relatedList>
 </body>
</apex:page>
```